# Bash: syntax error operand expected "=", in assignment statement in a for loop

Tags: linux, bash, for-loop, syntax-error

**EDIT**: I think that it's not picking up the $1 as the operand. I tried storing it in a variable, then trying the assignment but it seems that has no effect.

**EDIT 2**: provided a minimal reproducible script as requested.

The error generating part of the code is the following:

```sh
check() {
if [ $1 -lt $2 ]; then
 for((var=$1; var<$2; var++)); do
  if [ $((var%2)) -eq 0 ]; then
   echo "it's an even number"
   fi
  done
fi
}

if [ $# -eq 2 ]; then 
check
fi
```

the rest of the function's code will be attached below. The function is rather long to re-type out; I'm using ubuntu through a VM which doesn't allow for items to be copied into or pasted out of the VM, but this just may be a settings thing.

[part 1 of the function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQXZA.png)

[part 2 of the function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJnmZ.png)

Comment: Try quoting all your variables and see if it helps.

Comment: Q: What is an example value for `$1` when it fails?  Add `set -x` to your script to observe each statement, and each variable.

Comment: it fails in ever scenario $1 is just an interger number passed through the command line anywhere from 0 - what ever number the user goes up to.

Comment: I tried quoting variables seems to have no effect.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the code showing the problem. That is, take that one line of code and put it into a minimal script that reproduces the problem.

Comment: @Jetchisel : I don't think that quoting is necessary in the for loop. First of all, we have numeric context, where you don't need to quote. Assuming that the parameters are numbers (which is reasonable from the context), there is no embedded space anyway, and if there would be one (by passing an incorrect parameter), the program would already bail out at the preceding `if` statement.

Comment: @Nasri : Are you sure you are running this under bash? Do a `echo $BASH_VERSINFO` at the start of the `check` function to be sure.

Comment: @user1934428 I said try and see, I'm not interested in the for-loop since the error is in the `[` test.,  `[ $foo -lt 4 ]` an unquoted/non-existent variable gives you that error.

Comment: If it is me writing this I've save the positional parameter `$1`, `$2` `$3` in a variable so I can use it inside the arithmetic expression unquoted and and without the dollar sign, of course after I have sanitize/validate the input.

Comment: @Jetchisel : I thought this too first, but as GordonDavisson pointed out in his excellent comment below, `test` would not produce an error here in bash. You can try it using `test $foo -lt $bar` with unitialized foo and bar. I was not aware of this, because I'm usually using zsh, and in zsh this would be an error in this case, due to the zsh-specific rules for parameter expansion.

Comment: The lesson here is validate/sanitize input before blindly feeding it to your script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are invoking your function by

```
check
```

i.e. you don't pass any parameter, Hence, $1 and $2 are empty, so this can't work. You would have to write

```
check "$@"
```

or

```
check "$1" "$2"
```

depending on what exactly you want to achieve.

However, with your original code, you should then get for your `if` statement an error message

```
[: -lt: unary operator expected
```

**UPDATE**: As GordonDavisson pointed out in his comment, you won't get this syntax error here, because both operands are missing in your case and `-lt` then looses its meaning of being treated as operator.

BTW, if you had written the test as

```
if (( $1 < $2 )); then
```

you would have received a syntax error (*bash: ((: < : syntax error: operand expected (error token is "< ")*)

Comment: Thank you very much the script is now working, I didn't receive that error message for my if statement for some reason.

Comment: If I were programming this, I would research why there is no error message on the `[`. A system not reporting an obvious error, is a bit creepy, and certainly not something I would ignore. You may want to post a new question for this topic, if you can't find it out by yourself.

Comment: @Nasri: BTW, you can write your tests on `var` simpler as, i.e. `if (( var%2 == 0 )); then`.

Comment: @user1934428 You get the "unary operator expected" error if *one* of the operands is missing. If both are missing, `[ -lt ]` is interpreted as a valid expression meaning "is the string '-lt' nonempty?", and the answer is yes, so it actually returns success. In other words, it is *completely* misinterpreting what the expression is supposed to mean. This is yet another example of why you should put double-quotes around variable/parameter references.

Comment: @GordonDavisson : Good point. I will edit my answer in this respect.